# How do i get image url from custom feilds anywhare

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<?php 
    echo $image_url = get_field('video_tab_thumb');
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var tab_img_url = "<?php echo $image_url; ?>";
</script>
```

**I want this URL anywhere but it's showing only post page   **

Comment: You can create [Options Page](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/options-page/)

Answer (score 0):

You have different ways

1. **Store it in the database and fetch in anywhere**
2. **Use the cache and store it for example in the redis or file or somewhere eles and then fetch it**
3. **Store it in the session and get it again anywhere**

And ... 
They are just some ways that comes to my mind and I hope this could help you

Comment: (IMHO) This is more a list of ideas than any solutions.